# Recursive set for a string

Tags: recursion

Given the definition:

```
Let Σ be the alphabet defined as follows:  Σ = {e, l, v} 
We now define the set of strings P according to the following: 
BASIS STEP: If x ∈ Σ then x ∈ P 
RECURSIVE STEP: If w ∈ P and x ∈ Σ, then xwx ∈ P
```

> How to show that the string *level* is in P.

I do understand what is being asked and that I must use the recursive step to produce the target string. But I just don't know exactly how to go about it in a way that is efficient and accurate. Any help with an explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about

$$ v \in \Sigma \Longrightarrow v \in P $$
and $$v \in P \land e \in \Sigma \Longrightarrow eve \in P $$ so $$ eve \in P \land l \in \Sigma \Longrightarrow \boxed{level \in P}$$